# Context confusion regarding cancellation

Tags: go

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func myfunc(ctx context.Context) {
    for {
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            fmt.Printf("Ctx is kicking in with error:%+v\n", ctx.Err())
            return
        default:
            time.Sleep(15 * time.Second)
            fmt.Printf("I was not canceled\n")
            return
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(
        context.Background(),
        time.Duration(3*time.Second))
    defer cancel()

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        myfunc(ctx)
    }()

    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Printf("In main, ctx err is %+v\n", ctx.Err())
}
```

I have the above snippet that does print the output like this

```
I was not canceled
In main, ctx err is context deadline exceeded

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I understand that `context` times-out after 3 seconds and hence it does give me the expected error when I call `ctx.Err()` in the end. I also get the fact that in my `myfunc` once `select` matches on the case for `default`, it won't match on the `done`. What I do not understand is that how do I make my `go func myfunc` get aborted in 3 seconds using the context logic. Basically, it won't terminate in 3 seconds so I am trying to understand how can golang's `ctx` help me with this?

Comment: I appreciate the questions like these which are to the point and show some actual homework done before just asking.

Answer (score 45):

If you want to use the *timeout and cancellation* feature from the context, then *in your case* the `ctx.Done()` need to be handled synchronously.

Explanation from https://golang.org/pkg/context/#Context

> Done returns a channel that's closed when work is done on behalf of this context should be canceled. Done may return nil if this context can never be canceled. Successive calls to Done return the same value.

So basically the `<-ctx.Done()` will be called on two conditions:

1. when context timeout exceeds
2. when context canceled by force

And when that happens, the `ctx.Err()` will never be `nil`.

We can perform some checking on the error object to see whether the context is canceled by force or exceeding the timeout.

Context package provides two error objects, `context.DeadlineExceeded` and `context.Timeout`, this two will help us to identify why `<-ctx.Done()` is called.

---

### Example #1 scenario: context cancelled by force (via `cancel()`)

In the test, we'll try to make the context to be canceled before the timeout exceeds, so the `<-ctx.Done()` will be executed.

```golang
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(
    context.Background(),
    time.Duration(3*time.Second))

go func(ctx context.Context) {
    // simulate a process that takes 2 second to complete
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)

    // cancel context by force, assuming the whole process is complete
    cancel()
}(ctx)

select {
case <-ctx.Done():
    switch ctx.Err() {
    case context.DeadlineExceeded:
        fmt.Println("context timeout exceeded")
    case context.Canceled:
        fmt.Println("context cancelled by force. whole process is complete")
    }
}
```

Output:

```sh
$ go run test.go 
context cancelled by force
```

---

### Example #2 scenario: context timeout exceeded

In this scenario, we make the process takes longer than context timeout, so ideally the `<-ctx.Done()` will also be executed.

```golang
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(
    context.Background(),
    time.Duration(3*time.Second))

go func(ctx context.Context) {
    // simulate a process that takes 4 second to complete
    time.Sleep(4 * time.Second)

    // cancel context by force, assuming the whole process is complete
    cancel()
}(ctx)

select {
case <-ctx.Done():
    switch ctx.Err() {
    case context.DeadlineExceeded:
        fmt.Println("context timeout exceeded")
    case context.Canceled:
        fmt.Println("context cancelled by force. whole process is complete")
    }
}
```

Output:

```sh
$ go run test.go 
context timeout exceeded
```

---

### Example #3 scenario: context canceled by force due to error occurred

There might be a situation where we need to stop the goroutine in the middle of the process because error occurred. And sometimes, we might need to retrieve that error object on the main routine.

To achieve that, we need an additional channel to transport the error object from goroutine into main routine.

In the below example, I've prepared a channel called `chErr`. Whenever error happens in the middle of (goroutine) process, then we will send that error object through the channel and then stop process immediately from.

```golang
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(
    context.Background(),
    time.Duration(3*time.Second))

chErr := make(chan error)

go func(ctx context.Context) {
    // ... some process ...

    if err != nil {
        // cancel context by force, an error occurred
        chErr <- err
        return
    }

    // ... some other process ...

    // cancel context by force, assuming the whole process is complete
    cancel()
}(ctx)

select {
case <-ctx.Done():
    switch ctx.Err() {
    case context.DeadlineExceeded:
        fmt.Println("context timeout exceeded")
    case context.Canceled:
        fmt.Println("context cancelled by force. whole process is complete")
    }
case err := <-chErr:
    fmt.Println("process fail causing by some error:", err.Error())
}
```

---

### Additional info #1: calling `cancel()` right after context initialized

As per [context documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/context/#Context) regarding the `cancel()` function:

> Canceling this context releases resources associated with it, so code should call cancel as soon as the operations running in this Context complete.

It's good to always call `cancel()` function right after the context declaration. doesn't matter whether it's also called within the goroutine. This is due to ensure context is always cancelled when the whole process within the block are fully complete.

```golang
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(
    context.Background(),
    time.Duration(3*time.Second))
defer cancel()

// ...
```

---

### Additional info #2: `defer cancel()` call within goroutine

You can use `defer` on the `cancel()` statement within the goroutine (if you want).

```golang
// ...

go func(ctx context.Context) {
    defer cancel()

    // ...
}(ctx)

// ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the example. Just a question regarding the section of code:

    // simulate a process that takes 4 second to complete
    time.Sleep(4 * time.Second)

This process will still be running for another second. Do you have a suggestion for cancelling that process? Should you just pass on the context?

Comment: Very useful examples, thanks. Just wondering about something in example #3 in the case of an error passed through errCh the context is never cancelled. Why is this? Can it be solved with additional info #2, or cancelling in the errCh select case?

Comment: @particulator the limitation of #2 is actually you cannot pas the detailed error information. when you force cancel it by `cancel()` then what you get on the `ctx.Err()` is always `context.Canceled`. there will be a situation that you might want to pass the detailed error object that causing the context to be cancelled. you can use #3, or you can use #2 with additional `chan error` variable to hold the detailed error object

Comment: The question also asks how to abort a running function once the timeout is reached. Could you enhance your answer to include that?

Answer (score 30):

In your `for ... select`, you have 2 cases: `case <-ctx.Done():` and `default:`. When your code reaches the `select`, it enters the `default` case because the context is not yet cancelled, where it sleeps for 15 seconds and then returns, breaking your loop. (in other words, it isn't blocking/waiting for your context to cancel)

If you want your code to do what you are describing, you need your `select` to have cases for the context being cancelled *and* your imposed timeout.

```
select {
case <-ctx.Done(): // context was cancelled
  fmt.Printf("Ctx is kicking in with error:%+v\n", ctx.Err())
  return
case <-time.After(15 * time.Second): // 15 seconds have elapsed
  fmt.Printf("I was not canceled\n")
  return
}
```

Now, your code will block when it hits `select`, rather than entering the `default` case and breaking your loop.

Comment: This answer actually points out the root cause.

Comment: This should be selected as the answer.

Comment: This is not a practical function implementation. You are using "time.After" to represent a "Long task". In practical scenarios how do we implement a function that has an actual long task running and also that aborts the function once the timeout is reached?

Comment: @JainamMJ , found any solution?

Comment: @JainamMJ I believe what you'd need to do there is pass a channel into the long-running function (on a separate goroutine) and `select` in there to exit early

Comment: @TedBrownlow yes that must work..