# When will the Context of grpc.ServerStream be done?

Tags: go, stream, grpc

I have a server-side stream grpc interface.
This interface will wait for events and continuously send the event to the client.

I encountered a bug， the grpc stream will disconnect intermittently.

In my server, I use `server.Context().Done()` to detect anomalies and perform reconnection.

```golang
    go func() {
        <-server.Context().Done()
        log.Println(server.Context().Err())
        cancel()
    }()
```

When the problem occurs, the log will output "context canceled".

I want to know under what circumstances the channel server.Context().Done() will be closed, and the log will print "context canceled".

I checked the client and there is no code like context cancel.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is a duplicate, you can check here for some more explanations:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52799280/context-confusion-regarding-cancellation